# need to get better code to read file into variables

Tags: c

Currently have this code (see below). It was working fine, but I needed to be able to manage empty lines, and also lines with comment. These comment lines are defined as : having "#" as the first character of a line. Initially, I would just loop 100 times, because I limit the storage into variable to 100 as well, but when skipping empty lines and remark lines, the simple counter to 100 doesn't work. Still, only the first 100 valid lines may be read, and stored into the "menu_choices" variable. Also, the length of each line should be limited to 100 characters (or, I have a variable of 100 characters, so 99+enter). I'll need to include that as well. I can't decide wheter I need an IF statement, or a while, or whatever.

```
int x;  
char inputfile[512];  
char menu_number[100];  
char menu_choices[100][100];  

printf("\nopening:%s\n",inputfile);  
p_datafile=fopen(inputfile,"r");  

x=1;  
//for (x=1 ; x <= 100 ; x++ )  
do  
{
    // read next line into variable  
    fgets(menu_choices[x],100,p_datafile);  
    if ( strcmp ( menu_choices[x] , "" ) == 0 ) break;  
    if ( strncmp(menu_choices[x],"#",1) )  
    {  
        printf("%d[lngth=%d]=%s",x,strlen(menu_choices[x]),menu_choices[x]);  
        x++;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        printf("\n LINE WITH #");  
    }  
    sleep (1);  
} while (1);  

fclose(inputfile);
```

Can you improve the above code ?

Comment: Here did all the backticks come from?  At first, I had an overwhelming compunction to clean my display screen.

Comment: Wots the 'sleep(1)' for?   Your program was working too well?

Comment: What is the question?  What is it doing wrong?

Comment: `while (1);` -> `while (x<100);`

Comment: The sleep allows to read what the program is doing, when reading a given file. It's only there for debugging purposes.

Comment: Scott: the code is not doing what my intention is, as described in the opening post. Did you read that ?

Comment: `if ((srtncmp(menu_choices[x], "#", 1))` could be `if (menu_choices[x][0] != '#')` and `if (strcmp(menu_choices[x], "") == 0)` could be `if (menu_choices[x][0] == 0)` And you are stopping to read when you encounter an empty line, is that what you intend? Or may be you mean `continue;`?

Comment: No no, it may not stop on an empty line. In the old condition, it was OK since I had no empty lines, but it actually should read the entire file, or if 100 valid lines are read. It would be very nice then a message to be displayed as well, stating more than 100 valid lines are seen, but omitted from reading. Just that message, not the lines of data itself.

Comment: C arrays are `0` index based. That means that the first element of an array in C is the `0th` element not the `1st` element.

Comment: any reason you din't check for the success of `fopen()`?

Comment: Ghosh: I ... forgot that. Yes, there must be a check on file opening.

Comment: Iharob : Please elaborate. Oh yes, now I understand. No, I deliberately started with 1, since it's easier to handle afterwards. Choice 1 is stored as 1, 2 as 2, etc. Otherwise, 1 would be 0, 2 would be 1, etc. I don't mind losing 1 entry, I'm figuring : I have 16 Gigs of memory, no need to pick ants.

Comment: Some other reason you didnt initialize `inputfile`?

Comment: Iharob: I forgot why that was needed. I could open a file, and I was happy. That basically was it. Then I needed to ignore empty lines. I didn't say I couldn't read a file, did I ? But, you may be right, I'm not following the expert rules. Hey, maybe that is that what I'm asking.

Comment: `fgets(menu_choices[x],100,p_datafile);` --> `if (fgets(menu_choices[x], sizeof menu_choices[x], p_datafile) == NULL) break;`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing code.

Comment: I'm very sure I could improve the above code, but that's not what this site is for. Try asking a specific question about something you are trying to figure out, rather than "would someone please do my project better"...

Comment: It's not a project, the code shown is just part of a larger piece of code. In the example shown I had put the relevant stuff, so that the answers would be relevant. I could have put the question more clearer, but basically it's how to loop (for, while, ..) and what to use as a command to read the file (fgets, getc, ..). I cannot show less, because a lot relates to the loop I'm proposing to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you describe, may be this could work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main()
{
    int   lineCount;
    char  filename[512];
    /* if you want to read 100 characters you need 1 extra for the termination 0 */
    char  menu_choices[100][100 + 1 /* termination 0 */];
    int   extraLines;
    int   lineLength;
    FILE *p_datafile; // p_datafile was not declared...
    int   character;
    int   skipLine;

    printf("enter filename please: ");
    scanf("%511s", filename);
    printf("\topening:%s\n", filename);

    lineCount  = 0;
    p_datafile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (p_datafile == NULL)
        return 0; // or perhaps return a value, since there is no context here I don't know
    memset(menu_choices[0], 0, 101);

    extraLines = 0;
    lineLength = 0;
    skipLine   = 0;
    while ((p_datafile != NULL) && ((character = getc(p_datafile)) != EOF))
    {
        if (character == '\n')
        {
            if ((lineLength > 0) && (skipLine == 0))
            {

                menu_choices[lineCount][lineLength] = 0;
                lineCount                          += 1;

                printf("valid line %d [length -> %d] -> %s\n", lineCount, lineLength, menu_choices[lineCount - 1]);

                memset(menu_choices[lineCount], 0, 101);
            }
            else if (skipLine != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "line starts with #\n");
                extraLines += 1;
            }
            else if (lineLength == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "line is empty\n");
                extraLines += 1;
            }
            skipLine   = 0;
            lineLength = 0;
        }
        else if ((lineLength == 0) && (isspace(character) != 0))
        {
            /* Ignore spaces if non-space characters where not found yet. */
        }
        else
        {
            if ((lineLength == 0) && (character == '#'))
                skipLine = 1; /* Ignore this line, it starts with */
            else if (lineLength < 100)
            {
                menu_choices[lineCount][lineLength] = (char)character;
                lineLength                         += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(p_datafile); // the FILE * not the filename

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edited the question, and placed the `while (feof(p_datafile) == 0)` at the begining because if the file is empty then `fgets` will not read anything any way.

Comment: Did you test this answer @tvCa?

Comment: `while (feof(p_datafile) == 0)`? is that the idea?

Comment: He needs to read a file with more than 100 lines and skip empty lines or those starting with `#` so the `for` loop will only work if he updates the counter only everytime a valid line was found. From this you can see that the `while` loop is better, and if he is not interested in the total count of unread lines he can just `while ((feof(p_datafile) == 0) && (x < 100))`

Comment: I just noticed, that the `continue` line prevents updating `extraLines` counter.

Comment: I've picked this answer cause the code usage seems the best to me. Despite that, this code does still read the empty lines! Also, and this is much more of a problem, it's reading the remainder of the 100 bytes of each line that has 100 bytes. I may not have been clear enough about it, but I want the remainder after 100 characters of each line, to be forgotten. The FGETS function now just continue reading as if that is a new line. I think I need to read into a temporarily variable (which superlong length), then cut it off, and put that into the wanted character variable.

Comment: Did you read the manual for `fgets` it reads at least `size - 1` characters or until a `'\n'` or `EOF` appears. Also, may be empty lines are not empty, they could be all spaces, so my advice is you read one character at a time, ignore spaces if no nonspace character has been read and stop when you have 100 characters read, then keep reading until the end of line discarding all characters, and continue with the next line.

Comment: I acknowledge that, but in order to get FGETS to behave as I'm needing, some other changes are needed. Particularly since I am inserting straight into the target character variables, but the input needs modification, before I can do that. - I still want to get it working with FGETS, I just need some changes. I'm undo-ing this answer again, as it seems less than than I first thought. - And indeed, lines with only spaces are a problem too. But that's another problem.

Comment: The above code fails if more than 100 lines are read, because it doesn't enter the loop again where the read command (FGETS) occurs, and thus the program hangs, because it's waiting on a check that doesn't occur anymore. It just sleeps, then sees X bigger than 100, sleeps again, and repeats that. The read (FGETS) must occur outside the check on X.

Comment: @tvCa, look at the updated code, is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure if i have understood your question, but it seems following points can help you to achieve your goal.

1. add a `NULL` check on `p_datafile` to check the success of `fopen()`. [assuming `p_datafile` is already defined as `FILE *`, which part you din't show us.]
2. instead of `break;` after `if ( strcmp ( menu_choices[x] , "" ) == 0 )`, use `continue`.
3. add a `continue;` after `printf("\n LINE WITH #");` inside `else` block.
4. after `if...else` block, check if (`x == 100`), if true, `break;`
5. in `fclose()`, use `p_datafile`. It expects the file pointer, not the filename.

Comment: 3. does not make sense except for skipping `sleep`.

Comment: 4. is much easier if he uses a `for` loop.

Comment: Iharob : basically, that's one of the biggest questions : what kind of loop do I have to use ? The FOR loop was good for the initial usage, but it wasn't for the current need. I switched to something, but that is a bad choice I think. I'm sequentially reading a file, must be an easy way for that, no ?

Comment: See my answer, with the for loop you will never know how many lines you skipped and if the file has less than 100 lines, then you will be in trouble. But reading to the end of file then you can.

Comment: @iharob `how many lines you skipped.`.. where did you find this requirement?

Comment: Knowing how many lines are skipped, is nice but not essential. I sort of show that as part of debugging. Being able to read files with more than 100 lines (not all being valid), is a requirement though.

Comment: In one of @tvCa comments, he says _It would be very nice then a message to be displayed as well, stating more than 100 valid lines are seen,_

Comment: But that says : more than 100 valid lines. It's something else than counting invalid rows, and showing that counter. ;) But, I'm a control freak, so if there is a means of counting/showing, why not. But, if the file being read is way longer than 100 lines, I don't want 80,000 lines being scrolled over the console, since if it is bigger, it can be anything. Can even be binary, if mistakes are made.

Comment: @tvCa nobody said anything about printing the invalid line. iharob suggested a count for _invalid_ lines. the loop will depend on the value of `x` reaching 100.

Answer (score 0):

One answer was just before me but I'll post anyway. Bear in mind that `fgets()` reads the `newline` too, so I have tested for/ removed it. Also, your indexing: as far as possible use 0-based indexing, and make any adjustments between `0..` and `1..` for the human at the point of input and output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int x, len;  
    char inputfile[512] = "lines.txt";
    char menu_number[100];  
    char menu_choices[100][100];  
    FILE *p_datafile;

    printf ("\nopening:%s\n",inputfile);  
    p_datafile=fopen (inputfile,"rt");           // it's a text file
    if (p_datafile == NULL) {
        printf ("Can't open file %s\n", inputfile);
        exit (1);
    }

    x = 0;                  // get the array indexing right  
    while (x<100 && fgets(menu_choices[x], 100, p_datafile)) {
        if (menu_choices[x][0] != '\n' && menu_choices[x][0] != '#') {
            len = strlen (menu_choices[x]);
            if (menu_choices[x][len-1] == '\n')  // remove newline
                menu_choices[x][len-1] = 0;
            printf ("%s\n", menu_choices[x]);
            // sleep (1);  
            x++;
        }
    }

    fclose(p_datafile);     // corrected mistake (don't use filename)
    return 0;
}
```

Input file:

```
Line 1
Line 02

#not line 3
line three
```

Program output:

```
opening:lines.txt
Line 1
Line 02
line three
```

Comment: I noted as well that FGETS reads the enter, and I worked my way around it (particularly when printing), but it don't need to read the enter character. It's only the separator on input, if the line is less than 100 characters.

Comment: "it don't need to read the enter character." It *does* read the `newline` character, that's what `fgets()` does.

Comment: The above code works good, but it also has the problem as mentioned above with not cutting off the characters after 100 bytes. It reads that as a subsequent line. But, this is one is removing both the #-lines and the empty lines!